# How to prevent a virtual method from always being compiled?

Tags: c++, class, compilation, arduino, virtual-functions

While working on an Arduino library I've run into an interesting compilation problem. All the virtual methods in all classes get compiled... always. Even when the class is never constructed or even mentioned.

Example Arduino code that reproduces this issue:

```
class BaseClass {
  virtual void method();
};

void BaseClass::method() {
  Serial.println("This should not be compiled at all...");
}

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

Leaving out the BaseClass results in a final binary of 670 bytes. Including it, whilst never using the class, results in a code size of 3.354 bytes.

For a library containing a lot of classes that will frequently never be used at all, all containing a virtual `update()` routine, this sort of behavior is unacceptable. The only solution I have found so far is to force the user to include the header files for the components he wishes to use. Preferably, though, I would keep the library simple and not require the user to do this.

Is there an AVR method attribute that can tell the compiler to only compile a virtual method if the class is being constructed somewhere? Alternatively, are there compiler options that can enable me to optimize these unused virtual methods out?

Using the ATMEGA2560 AVR, with the G++ compiler. Current compiler options passed by Arduino:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=106 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\variants\mega
```

Comment: Maybe `-fvtable-gc` is what you want? ([Source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/C---Dialect-Options.html)) You may need additional options to actually toss out the method implementations.  See the link.

Comment: Looks like this is the solution, once I find a way to alter compiler options in the Arduino software I can tell for sure whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [-fno-implicit-templates](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html) you might solve you immediate problem, you will have to instantiate those templates explicitly you do use.

Your users will have to include a header with the full implementation of all none-instantiated templates and use the right flags/explicit instantiate for those they use.

Comment: Marking this one as the accepted answer to mark thread as answered. This is likely an equally acceptable solution, though I have not managed to try it out yet.